# No need of continuous with while?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> *They met one day while John's father was reading a book in the library and his mother sat down beside him.*

Why it is not **was sitting**? Is it because of the while conjunction. Have both actions the same duration as normally past continuous indicates that the action is longer than  with past simple.Or maybe two "verb+ing"s do not sound nice.

Comment: Lucian has given a good answer. But I just wanted to point out that the difference between past continuous and past simple is *not* that the continuous action is understood to be "longer" than an action expressed with past simple; rather, the past simple action is presented as one that happened, without any reference whatsoever to its duration.  Duration  does not come into the picture with past simple.  A line segment is not longer than a point, right, because a point has no length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, the sentence creates the image of John's father reading a book while his mother came and sat down beside him. So, his reading was interrupted by her presence.

If **was sitting** were used, then both actions that of reading and that of sitting could be regarded as occurring simultaneously for a certain amount of time.

Consequently, both versions are correct but they may imply slightly different pictures.

Comment: It could be that it is grammatically correct, for the reasons you have given. More likely, I suspect, is that it is a frequently made grammatical error. In various north of England accents, it is perfectly common to hear the past participle of a verb, substituted for what should be the present participle, especially when employing the past continuous (imperfect tense).  *I was sat in the library, when a tall man walked in*. I suspect the sample sentence, in standard English, should read *...and his mother sitting down beside him*